# Cannot use html_nodes in a world bank webpage

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest, httr

I would like to get all the news title and short description of the WB webpge but it returns "character (0)".

Here is what I did:

```
 # News of WB
link_wb <- "http://www.worldbank.org/en/news/all?displayconttype_exact=Speeches+and+Transcripts&lang_exact=English&qterm="
wb_speechs <- read_html(link_wb)

# get the news title
wb_title <- wb_speechs %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = "/html/body/div[4]/div/div/customsearch/main/div/div/div/div[2]/news/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/ul/li/div/h4") %>%
  html_text()
wb_title
```

I've tried with some class, xpath and so on, but get no results. Please advice! Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The BIG loading delay spinner thingy is an indicator they load the content asynchronously via XHR requests (this is a pretty extensively covered topic on the web and on SO if you do *any* research on web scraping).

If you open Developer Tools on your browser and reload the site you can see the request:

[image]

If you right-click on the highlighted URL there's even a handy "Copy URL" (or something like that — diff browsers do diff things).

BUT, there's also a "Copy as cURL" in most browsers and you can use [`curlconverter`](http://github.com/hrbrmstr/curlconverter) to make `httr` verb functions automagically with them (read the docs and try it or search SO for examples as I've posted tons):

```
httr::POST(
  url = "http://search.worldbank.org/api/v2/news",
  httr::add_headers(
    `User-Agent` = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:64.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/64.0",
    Accept = "application/json, text/plain, */*",
    `Accept-Language` = "en-US,en;q=0.7,fr-BE;q=0.3",
    Referer = "http://www.worldbank.org/en/news/all?displayconttype_exact=Speeches+and+Transcripts&lang_exact=English&qterm=",
    Origin = "http://www.worldbank.org",
    DNT = "1", Connection = "keep-alive",
    `Cache-Control` = "max-age=0"
  ),
  body = list(),
  query = list(
    format = "json",
    rows = "20",
    fct = "displayconttype_exact,topic_exact,lang_exact,count_exact,countcode_exact,admreg_exact",
    src = "cq55",
    apilang = "en",
    displayconttype_exact = "Speeches+and+Transcripts",
    lang_exact = "English",
    qterm = ""
  )
) -> res

str(httr::content(res)$documents, 2)
## List of 21
##  $ 0f3dcce9e42a42509f35c1a3744f6768954e82ff:List of 20
##   ..$ url             : chr "http://www.worldbank.org/en/news/speech/2018/11/05/world-bank-group-president-jim-yong-kims-remarks-at-the-open"| __truncated__
##   ..$ id              : chr "0f3dcce9e42a42509f35c1a3744f6768954e82ff"
##   ..$ title           :List of 1
##   ..$ descr           :List of 1
##   ..$ wcmsource       : chr "cq5"
##   ..$ cqpath          : chr "/content/wb-home/en/news/speech/2018/11/05/world-bank-group-president-jim-yong-kims-remarks-at-the-opening-cere"| __truncated__
##   ..$ content         :List of 1
##   ..$ content_1000    :List of 1
##   ..$ admreg          : chr "East Asia and Pacific"
##   ..$ displayconttype : chr "Speeches and Transcripts"
##   ..$ country         : chr "China"
##   ..$ originating_unit: chr "East Asia and Pacific, EAP"
##   ..$ countcode       : chr "CN"
##   ..$ count           : chr "China"
##   ..$ regionname      : chr "East Asia and Pacific"
##   ..$ topic           : chr "Trade"
##   ..$ conttype        : chr "Speeches and Transcripts"
##   ..$ lang            : chr "English"
##   ..$ keywd           : chr "regions:East Asia and Pacific,country:China,subject:trade"
##   ..$ lnchdt          : chr "2018-11-05T17:11:00Z"
##  $ 82c9d8ffa337303aa54b7cf23fabc062c76a3fab:List of 13
##   ..$ url             : chr "http://www.worldbank.org/en/news/speech/2018/11/05/remarks-at-eu-high-level-conference-the-single-market-as-a-d"| __truncated__
##   ..$ id              : chr "82c9d8ffa337303aa54b7cf23fabc062c76a3fab"
##   ..$ title           :List of 1
##   ..$ descr           :List of 1
##   ..$ wcmsource       : chr "cq5"
##   ..$ cqpath          : chr "/content/wb-home/en/news/speech/2018/11/05/remarks-at-eu-high-level-conference-the-single-market-as-a-driver-of"| __truncated__
##   ..$ content         :List of 1
##   ..$ content_1000    :List of 1
##   ..$ displayconttype : chr "Speeches and Transcripts"
##   ..$ originating_unit: chr "External and Corporate Relations, ECR"
##   ..$ conttype        : chr "Speeches and Transcripts"
##   ..$ lang            : chr "English"
##   ..$ lnchdt          : chr "2018-11-05T09:59:00Z"
##  $ 527850d45d63a534497c985b0ff71970812668f9:List of 20
##   ..$ url             : chr "http://www.worldbank.org/en/news/speech/2018/11/01/world-bank-group-president-jim-yong-kim-remarks-at-the-inter"| __truncated__
##   ..$ id              : chr "527850d45d63a534497c985b0ff71970812668f9"
##   ..$ title           :List of 1
##   ..$ descr           :List of 1
##   ..$ wcmsource       : chr "cq5"
##   ..$ cqpath          : chr "/content/wb-home/en/news/speech/2018/11/01/world-bank-group-president-jim-yong-kim-remarks-at-the-international"| __truncated__
##   ..$ content         :List of 1
##   ..$ content_1000    :List of 1
##   ..$ admreg          : chr "East Asia and Pacific"
##   ..$ displayconttype : chr "Speeches and Transcripts"
##   ..$ country         : chr "China"
##   ..$ originating_unit: chr "East Asia and Pacific, EAP"
##   ..$ countcode       : chr "CN"
##   ..$ count           : chr "China"
##   ..$ regionname      : chr "East Asia and Pacific"
##   ..$ topic           : chr "Poverty,Economic Growth"
##   ..$ conttype        : chr "Speeches and Transcripts"
##   ..$ lang            : chr "English"
##   ..$ keywd           : chr "subject:poverty,People:Jim Yong Kim,subject:economic growth,regions:East Asia and Pacific,country:China"
##   ..$ lnchdt          : chr "2018-11-01T15:15:00Z"
##  $ 5bf8d923c6defbb00be5eb454a0505168ce38d4f:List of 13
##   ..$ url             : chr "http://www.worldbank.org/en/news/speech/2018/10/31/opening-remarks-by-country-director-for-western-balkans-lind"| __truncated__
##   ..$ id              : chr "5bf8d923c6defbb00be5eb454a0505168ce38d4f"
##   ..$ title           :List of 1
##   ..$ descr           :List of 1
##   ..$ wcmsource       : chr "cq5"
##   ..$ cqpath          : chr "/content/wb-home/en/news/speech/2018/10/31/opening-remarks-by-country-director-for-western-balkans-linda-van-ge"| __truncated__
##   ..$ content         :List of 1
##   ..$ content_1000    :List of 1
##   ..$ displayconttype : chr "Speeches and Transcripts"
##   ..$ originating_unit: chr "Europe and Central Asia, ECA"
##   ..$ conttype        : chr "Speeches and Transcripts"
##   ..$ lang            : chr "English"
##   ..$ lnchdt          : chr "2018-10-31T13:51:00Z"
##  $ 3c00ec85c4ba38a7952a1a13b2c00a789f7eebd3:List of 13
##   ..$ url             : chr "http://www.worldbank.org/en/news/speech/2018/10/31/remarks-by-cyril-muller-on-investing-in-human-capital-for-inclusive-growth"
##   ..$ id              : chr "3c00ec85c4ba38a7952a1a13b2c00a789f7eebd3"
##   ..$ title           :List of 1
##   ..$ descr           :List of 1
##   ..$ wcmsource       : chr "cq5"
##   ..$ cqpath          : chr "/content/wb-home/en/news/speech/2018/10/31/remarks-by-cyril-muller-on-investing-in-human-capital-for-inclusive-growth"
##   ..$ content         :List of 1
##   ..$ content_1000    :List of 1
##   ..$ displayconttype : chr "Speeches and Transcripts"
##   ..$ originating_unit: chr "Europe and Central Asia, ECA"
##   ..$ conttype        : chr "Speeches and Transcripts"
##   ..$ lang            : chr "English"
##   ..$ lnchdt          : chr "2018-10-31T08:04:00Z"
##  $ 2b85fb0a48c1693f79b79803f659d3449a4c4348:List of 13
##   ..$ url             : chr "http://www.worldbank.org/en/news/speech/2018/10/24/opening-remarks-at-sovereign-debt-management-forum"
##   ..$ id              : chr "2b85fb0a48c1693f79b79803f659d3449a4c4348"
##   ..$ title           :List of 1
##   ..$ descr           :List of 1
##   ..$ wcmsource       : chr "cq5"
##   ..$ cqpath          : chr "/content/wb-home/en/news/speech/2018/10/24/opening-remarks-at-sovereign-debt-management-forum"
##   ..$ content         :List of 1
##   ..$ content_1000    :List of 1
##   ..$ displayconttype : chr "Speeches and Transcripts"
## ... GOES ON A LONG TIME ..
```

You can also just (most of the time) use the plain URL but the `httr`/`curlconverter` method makes it something you can wrap in a function and parameterize.